# initWithCoder and encodeWithEncoder hell. Can this be simplified?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nscoder, initwithcoder

With dozens of models with dozens of properties each, all able to be saved to disk using the `NSCoder` protocol and `NSKeyed(Un)archiver`, it's a lot of work to create and maintain models for my iOS application. With a dozen of properties for one model, I have to:

1. define a dozen of properties (which is ok, because they HAVE to be defined somewhere)
2. fill the `initWithCoder:` method, that's a dozen lines and two dozen times typing/copy-pasting the property name (or a constant key), 3) some goes for `encodeWithCoder:`.

The risk of mistakes (either in typing, copying or changing (or *not changing*) things like `encodeObject:` to `encodeInteger:` is huge. Besides, it's simply a lot of manual work, which I prefer not to do. After all, we have computers to do that for us.

First I looked into something like simplifying the work. Something like this:

```
#define encodeObject(x) [encoder encodeObject:[self valueForKey:x] forKey:x]
#define decodeObject(x) [self setValue:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:x] forKey:x]
```

But that is still a lot of work. Can't this be done any simpeler?
I do not prefer to do this on runtime using introspection or something.

I am thinking about some Python script that generates/manipulates the model files and adds them to Xcode. This could be based upon some JSON description file.

Having Xcode run this automatically in the pre-build phase would be great. Meaning a single place where I define every model and every property *once* and never having to worry about mistakes and properties I forgot to encode/decode.

Is the anything like that out there? Are there methods to add files to an Xcode project, without messing with some unreadable Apple "XML" project files? And what about including the headers in the target.. Or maybe some other great method to save me all that work?

Comment: I realise that you're probably not looking for a library to solve this, but certainly check out Mantle at https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle ... also, there's some cool KVC wizardry (with optional introspection discussion) located here: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/nscoding-without-boilerplate.html

Comment: Those are all options that make use of the runtime features.. What I most likely want is some code generation tool that creates the files for me.